# remove iFrame src data attribute on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a vimeo player which src ID is picked up from the attribute `data-vimeo` on a `div`.

Example below:

```
<div class="js-video-btn" data-vimeo="286031821">Button Link</div>
```

My iframe for the vimeo player looks like this

```
<iframe class="vimeo-frame" src='https://player.vimeo.com/video/' frameborder='0' webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

until it picks up the `data-vimeo` attribute which completes the `src` URL to this `https://player.vimeo.com/video/286031821`

I'm achieveing this with jQuery and its all working well. However what I would like to do is on click of another button it removes the data-vimeo attribute leaving the `src` URL as it was like so: `https://player.vimeo.com/video/`

Here is my jQuery:

```
$('.js-video-btn').click(function() {
    var video=$(this).data('vimeo');
    $('.vimeo-frame').attr('src', $('.vimeo-frame').attr('src') + video );
});

$('.video-close').click(function(){
    $('.vimeo-frame').removeAttr('src', $('.vimeo-frame').attr('src'));
});
```

I'm using removeAttr but this complete removes the whole URL and I only wanted to remove the `data-vimeo` ID. What is the best way to achieve this?

Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rysa3ecg/) too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all the characters after the last forward slash.
Also, not adding the video id more than once.

Here is a working demo:

```js
$(".js-video-btn").click(function() {
  var video = $(this).data("vimeo");
  var $videoFrame = $(".vimeo-frame");
  var src = $videoFrame.attr("src");

  // Make sure video id is not added twice
  if (src.length - 1 === src.lastIndexOf("/")) {
    $videoFrame.attr("src", src + video);
  }
});

$(".video-close").click(function() {
  var $videoFrame = $(".vimeo-frame");
  var src = $videoFrame.attr("src");
  
  // Trim the characters after the last forward slash
  $videoFrame.attr("src", src.substr(0, src.lastIndexOf("/") + 1));
});
```

```css
.link-txt {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.video-close {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="link-txt js-video-btn" data-vimeo="286031821">Button Link to add video to iframe</div>

<section class="video-popup">
  <div class="video-inner">
    <div class="clearfix">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary video-close">close video</button>
    </div>
    <div class='o-embed-container'>
      <iframe class="vimeo-frame" src='https://player.vimeo.com/video/' frameborder='0' webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you have a url that looks something like https://player.vimeo.com/video/123 and you just want https://player.vimeo.com/video/

If that is the case have a look at the code below, use this to set the src.

```
var test="https://player.vimeo.com/video/123"
test = test.substr(0,test.lastIndexOf("/"));
```

This will leave the result of "https://player.vimeo.com/video"

Comment: I would change the second line (although dirty), but your code removes the `/` which would then in retrospect make the adding of the videoid not work in this case. This:  `test.substr(0,test.lastIndexOf("/")+1);` would make it work with his solution. Created a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rysa3ecg/1/